# "You cannot change private secure settings" - how to toggle ringtone vibration in Android 6?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Due to recent changes in Android 6 Marshmallow regarding permissions, the following code no longer works and throws an exception.

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0);
```

This happens even after granting `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission to the app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getActivity().getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
//at this point Settings activity is opened and user is prompted for permission

...

if (Settings.System.canWrite(this)) { //now returns true, because permissions were granted
    Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0); //still crashes
} else {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "No permission to write settings.");
}
```

How can I change the ringtone vibration settings (and similar *secure settings*) in Android 6?

Full stack trace:

```
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.warnOrThrowForUndesiredSecureSettingsMutationForTargetSdk(SettingsProvider.java:1173)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.enforceRestrictedSystemSettingsMutationForCallingPackage(SettingsProvider.java:1030)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.mutateSystemSetting(SettingsProvider.java:906)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.insertSystemSetting(SettingsProvider.java:874)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:257)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:398)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:283)
10-12 02:26:37.728 1927-2765/? E/DatabaseUtils:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[DetectedActivityIntentService]
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime: Process: <package_name>, PID: 10084
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1322)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1671)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1776)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1770)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at <package_name>.DetectedActivityIntentService.activate(DetectedActivityIntentService.java:116)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at <package_name>.DetectedActivityIntentService.onHandleIntent(DetectedActivityIntentService.java:94)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-12 02:26:37.729 10084-11411/<package_name> E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but hopefully it will help - it appears that a lot of vibration settings were moved/changed in M. Taking a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html I'm seeing that at least 3 entries have the description: "Accessing this setting from an app that is targeting M or later throws a SecurityException".

Comment: I'm stuck at the same problem. There is no note about a security exception and this being a secure setting in the documentation.

Comment: According to the docs, you need to show system settings interface launching an activity with ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS action.   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: Stuck at the same point. Settings activity launched, permission granted. I am changing the mode from the widget, where it crashes with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings`

Answer (score 5):

## Because the **security**

as we know,in Android 6.0(Marshmallow),Android add lots of strategies to control the **SECURITY**, promote efficiency
such as :

- Runtime permission
- Doze mode(Power Manager)
- re-write **SettingsProviders**
  [see details](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/683914bfb13908bf380a25258cd45bcf43f13dc9)

  - move system settings from db to xml
  - /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/../settings.db --> /data/system/users/userid/settings_[system|global|secure].xml

## So Now(after API 22)

- you can **NOT** write some private/dangerous settings
- you **MUST** deal with some **EXCEPTION** during porting to API level 22 or later.
  [see details](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java)

## PS

[image: need deal with some EXCEPTION]

[image: can not change]

Comment: Thanks, but this answer is incorrect (or rather off-topic). I know that VIBRATE_WHEN_RINGING is a private secure setting, but my question remains open.

Comment: I was looking for where did settings.db had gone. This info was real hard to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194376&can=4&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) the problem seems to be resolved on Dec. 9th. Issue will be fixed in the future build.

Issue was openned by Stack Overflow member and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138280/vibrate-when-ringing-on-android-marshmallow-6-0).