# vibrate_when_ringing on Android Marshmallow (6.0)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-vibration, android-settings

In my code I have:

```
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", isVibrateWhenRinging ? 1 :0);
```

Using the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

This was working fine from Jelly Bean (API 16) till Lollipop (API 22).

In Android M, I know that for using that permission I need to prompt the user to [Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS).

However, even with that permission turned on, I see the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
```

Well... Am I missing something? With proper permissions we can change ringtones, do not disturb mode, etc. But it also looks like that with Android M we won't be able to change such a normal setting like "Vibrate when ringing". I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: It's not clear if it's a bug or not, however it's not possible  to write a lot of settings :(

Comment: I found out that if you set targetSdkVersion to 22 even if you are running in Android M, then changing vibrate_when_ringing will work. This seems as a bug to me in 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question. There is an issue opened to Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194376.

Basically, they partially fixed `vibrate_when_ringing` and it works again on Android N (24). Unfortunately, it does not work on Android M (23). For the response on the issue, it does not seem that is going to be fixed.

You can see a full example repo here: https://github.com/ferrannp/VibrateWhenRinging

So, basically, your code needs to check if your on Android M and if you are, do not use that setting.

Answer (score 2):

You should call Settings.System.canWrite() to see that you can to write this setting.

If function returns false then the user can agree to allow your app to write to settings:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I did that and I also prompt the user to Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS as I wrote in the question. I opened a bug for Google that has been passed to the development team: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194376&can=4&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened.